# Undefined result when printing Object property using Ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I try to access the object property outside the ajax when getting the value of an input it returns the correct value. But when I try to log and append that value inside the success function it returns undefined. How do I address this type of issue? It seems that object is local and cannot accessed by the ajax? Below is my code.

```
$('#add-order').on('click',function(){

    //create an object for orders
    var order = {   

        name : $('#name').val(),
        drink : $('#drink').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'api/orders.json',
        type : 'POST',
        data : order,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(newOrder){
            console.log(newOrder.name);
            $('#orders').append('<li>' + newOrder.name + ' : ' + newOrder.drink + '</li>');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error connecting');
        }
    });

});
```

Here's the index.html

```
<h4>Add a Coffee Order</h4>
<ul id="orders">

</ul>

<p><input type="text" id="name"></p>

<p><input type="text" id="drink"></p>

<button type="submit" id="add-order">Add</button>
```

Since I needed a server side language I used PHP. However I cannot write the data coming from the ajax using the JSON.stringify method.

```
    <?php

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $orders = $_POST['data'];
        $orderFile = fopen('api/orders.json', 'w');

       fwrite($orderFile, $orders);
       fclose($orderFile);
   }
```

I also updated my code on top.When I hard coded any string to fwrite($orderFile, "my orders") it will write on the orders.json however when I used the $orders it's not working. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newOrder` is the `JSON` returned by the AJAX call and it can have differnet keys depending upon what you are doing, if you want to print the `order` object then do

```
$('#orders').append('<li>' + order.name + ' : ' + order.drink + '</li>');
```

Comment: Ah got it. Yeah that's why when I log the newOrder it returns the data in it. Thank you so much.But one last question will the value I inputted in the input will be written to order.json file? If not how will I do it?

Comment: @JayGorio: Well, it *might* be written to the json file. That's what the server needs to do, all you can do clientside is to pass the data to the server through that POST request.

Comment: @Bergi i do not think it is being written, because the file name is `.json` and it can not do any server side processing.

Comment: @Beigi yeah its not being written. Ho do I deal with this?I thought it will automatically written when using POST method but it's not.

Comment: @void but if I change the extension will it be written?

Comment: @void: The file extension means absolutely nothing. Every server does need to do some processing to serve any requests at all. What the processing is depends entirely on its configuration/programming. Jay, please ask a new question where you show us your serverside code.

Comment: @Bergi Okay then. So I need to use php then.

Comment: @JayGorio: No, you don't *need*. Any serverside programming language (or even just a server framework that doesn't require programming) will do the job, which includes but is not exclusive to PHP.

Comment: @Bergi thanks can you check my server side code. It seems its not writing .

Comment: @JayGorio: As I said, you should [open a new question for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Tag it PHP. Show us where the php file is located. Is it even executed?

Comment: @JayGorio exactly, please open a new question for PHP related issues, and if this answer solves your current issue please consider marking it as right answer.

Comment: @Bergi oops okay sorry.

Comment: @Bergi heres the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454373/how-to-write-values-coming-from-form-input-to-json-using-php

Answer (score 0):

*But when I try to log and append that value inside the success function it returns `undefined`.*

That is because of your json file `orders.json` or the logic of serverside code. In the returned json `newOrder` in the success callback the object will not be having a key `name/drink` so that causes in `undefined`.

So, the thing is you have to return it from serverside with the specified keys, which should look like this:

```
{ "name":"Mango", "drink":"shake" }
```