# How to write values coming from form input to json using php

Tags: php, ajax

Since I needed a server side language I used PHP. However I cannot write the data coming from the ajax using the JSON.stringify method.

```
$('#add-order').on('click',function(){

    //create an object for orders
    var order = {   

        name : $('#name').val(),
        drink : $('#drink').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : 'add_order.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : order,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(newOrder){
            console.log(newOrder.name);
            $('#orders').append('<li>' + newOrder.name + ' : ' + newOrder.drink + '</li>');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error connecting');
        }
    });

});
```

Here's the index.php

```
<h4>Add a Coffee Order</h4>
<ul id="orders">

</ul>

<p><input type="text" id="name"></p>

<p><input type="text" id="drink"></p>

<button type="submit" id="add-order">Add</button>
```

add_order.php

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $orders = $_POST['data'];
        $orderFile = fopen('api/orders.json', 'w');

       fwrite($orderFile, $orders);
       fclose($orderFile);
   }
```

When I hard coded any string to fwrite($orderFile, "my orders") it will write on the orders.json however when I used the $orders it's not working. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Arent u writing it onto a JSON file, shouldnt u be writing it to the PHP file?and index.html should be index.php ;-)? or either replace the php code to correct file

Comment: @Tredged thanks for the reply yeah its index.php

Comment: If you're sending the POST request that should write the file to `api/orders.json`, your PHP code that writes the file shouldn't be sitting in `index.html`.

Comment: @Bergi oops typo error I edited the index.html to index.php

Comment: @Bergi please help I really need your help.

Comment: Now that you've fixed the issue with the resource URIs, your question is probably a dupe of [How can I use JQuery to post JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6255344/1048572)

Comment: Btw, if you expect `new_order` to have a value you'll need to respond back to the client with the written file.

Comment: @Bergi the link you gave I already did with the stringify method. It doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: @JayGorio: Where do you already use the `JSON.stringify` method? What exactly is the problem? What is the value you are getting for `$orders`?

Comment: @Bergi I already posted my solution anyways thanks for your long responses.

Answer (score 1):

you're posting to `api/orders.json` which is incorrect, you should be posting to the file that processes the request, like `index.php`.
Passing an object as the data parameter does not convert it to json, you have to actually do it yourself. So if you want `$_POST['data']` to hold the order data as json

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'index.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {data: JSON.strinify(order)},
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(newOrder){
        console.log(newOrder.name);
        $('#orders').append('<li>' + newOrder.name + ' : ' + newOrder.drink + '</li>');
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error connecting');
    }
});
```

Comment: Im writing it on a 'api/order.json' and my add_order.php is my url. Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I found already the solution. First I did was to serialize the inputs instead of using stringify.

```
    var order = {   
        name : $('#name').val(),
        drink : $('#drink').val()
    };     
    var inputs = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'add_order.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : inputs,
        dataType : 'json',
        //some codes here...
   });
```

Then in my php file which is the add_order.php, I fetch the values passed by the data and make them as an array. I also make used of file_get_contents to read on the json file and file_put_content to write on the file as json.

```
$ordersFile = 'api/orders.json';
$order = array();

//grab the form input 

$formData = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'drink' => $_POST['drink']
        );

$jsonOrders = file_get_contents($ordersFile);

$order = json_decode($jsonOrders, true);

echo json_encode($formData);

array_push($order, $formData);

file_put_contents($ordersFile, json_encode($order, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

But if you still have shorter solution then let me know.